# XCTestCase stops after failure

Tags: ios, swift, xcuitest, xctestcase

I have a XCTestCase, but if the test fail - the app quits right away.
I did change this line to the following:

```
continueAfterFailure = true
```

and it still quit the app after failure.
Does anyone know how to keep the app alive after UI test failure? Couldn't find a solution yet.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the app will get quit in the tearDown method after the test case is finished running. We need to override the tearDown method to terminate the app only when we want.

For example [XCUITest Class teardown isnt deleting the app. But works if its instance teardown. What am I doing wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53181823/xcuitest-class-teardown-isnt-deleting-the-app-but-works-if-its-instance-teardow/54710867#54710867)